# is redwood decorative bark mulch stained black bad for dogs?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, eating, poison

So, we want to add medium size redwood bark pieces (mulch) around our yard at the flower beds.  We have a 3mo. old German Shepherd pup.

Landscaper suggested black, but we are concerned that this is actually bark stained black.

She often chews on the bark.

Is this a health risk?

Answer (score 2):

How about just waiting a bit longer with the bark and for the potential problem to solve itself? Our dog (Siberian Husky) also chewed on bark chips for a while but this pretty much disappeared once he had his final teeth.

Besides that, we can't really tell, because we don't know what's actually in there. It might be harmless, it might be harmful. We can't tell.

Although keep in mind it's no problem for most dogs to swallow tiny bits of wood, this shouldn't become a habit, as it might lead to complications and health issues.